Logic behind equal charging time although one computer's charger consumes 200 W and the other 75 W
Recently, I came across two friends, one with a Macbook Pro (M3 Pro), the other one with an HP Omen. Both computers take one hour to charge.
The interesting thing here is that the Mac's got a 75 W charger, whereas the Omen has a 200 W charger (more than double the wattage).
Yet how is the Mac able to charge at the same speed at lower wattage?

Charger wattage is just one factor here. Initial load state may be different, battery capacity may be different, power management (software) may be different, and there probably are other relevant factors. The wattage on the charger just indicates the maximum wattage it can deliver if asked for.

HP could just produce one generic charger that is used across many models.
I know, from the models of laptops I have from Apple (MacBook Pro, MacBook Air, iPads etc), that there are chargers of various capacities - the lower capacity chargers will charge the bigger demand laptops over time but if they are in use that may not happen, while the more powerful chargers do not overcharge things. Case in point: usb C MacBook Pro charger used to directly charge my Apple Watch.
Batteries of different capacities may well have different charge rates so it is not what the charger can deliver but what the battery can use.

My HP laptop has a 65W charger :-)

Grateful to get the answer, Thank you everybody for giving your time
